# Create an Insert Parameter based off values of multiple fields - .NET

Tags: asp.net, parameters, formview, itemtemplate

I have an Insert screen which I want the values of two fields to be combined to create the value for a third field to be inserted as well. Currently I have a First and Last name field, as well as a Display name field (see below). The Display Name field should always be (First Name) + " " + (first letter of Last Name field). I want to save the user the hassle of having to manually type this in. How can I set the parameter "Dname" in the example below to take the value of the FName and LName fields and combine them for its value?

```
<asp:FormView ID="testFormView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="testDataSource">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        First Name: <asp:TextBox ID="First_NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FName") %>' />
        <br />
        Last Name: <asp:TextBox ID="Last_NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LName") %>' />
        <br />
        Display Name: <asp:TextBox ID="Display_NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DName") %>' />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert"  />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="testDataSource" runat="server"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Users] ([FName], [LName], [DName]) VALUES (@FName, @LName, @DName)">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="FName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="LName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DName" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I'm using C# in the code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to manually build the name and dump it into the textbox. Just attach a handler to the `blur` event on the first and last name textboxes. When you post, it will be as if the user typed it in themselves.

Or even better, move your data access out of your markup and put it into your actual code, and make your database calls properly using ADO.NET - this will give you the flexibility to build your commands exactly how you want them, and bind the parameters however you need.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of the javascript option, but wanted to avoid it. I actually just updated the InsertCommand, worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Found a really simple solution to this, just had to update the SQL query in the InsertCommand to the below:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="testDataSource" runat="server"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Users] ([FName], [LName], [DName]) VALUES (@FName, @LName, (@FName + ' ' + SUBSTRING(@LName, 1, 1)))">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="FName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="LName" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
```